# synchronization between windows services

Tags: c#, windows-services, synchronization

I have a windows service which simply reads a shared UNC folder (like watch folder) then picks up top 5 files and makes some process and transfer it to somewhere else via API.

This service scheduled to be run every 5 minutes. And processing&transferring can take more than 5 minutes.

I will run this windows service over 5 servers and I would like to find a solid approach that these services will not access same file at the same time.

I am thinking is that which ever service will access, first it will check SQL server if these files are on the processing list (like processing_files table). If not then write those file on the database and try to pick up them, so if there is another service tries access same folder it would check db and sees files are in process. Then it will try next 5 file.

I would like to know if there is a known/better approach for this scenario then I do not need to invent wheel again.

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL server for something like this seems overkill. It seems you have permissions to read/write to the folder so one approach would be to create an empty "lock" file when the file is being processed.

So when a server is processing a file, create the filename.ext.lock file in the directory. If another server sees this file, it knows to ignore the filename.ext file since its already being processed. If you want to get fancy, you can add information to the .lock file like what server is handling it, when it started, etc for debugging purposes. When the file is finished processing you can just delete the .lock file.

Answer (score 0):

File locking would be the simplest and most efficient approach.

When you open the file, you can choose whether or not to allow other processes to share the file.  If you don't, then only one process can open the file at the time; other processes will receive a sharing violation.

Assuming you are using .NET classes, that means an exception will be raised if the file you have selected is already in use.  You can catch the exception and try the next file on the list.

However, to use this approach you do need to be opening the file with a class that allows you to specify the sharing mode.  I believe most .NET classes do provide this functionality, either directly or indirectly.